# Swift: How to load external array to my UITableView

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, swift

I am learning Swift and I have pattern that I used to do in Objective C, but don't understand how to do it here.
I have UIViewController with TableView. I works fine when I put my array inside it. But according to MVC I want to move my array with data to another class. And I have no idea how to do it. Everything I tried doesn't work.
Thank you!

My code, how to move tableDS outside:

```
import UIKit
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {     

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    //temp table data
    let tableDS = ["fdf", "dfd"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tableDS.count
    }


    let textCellIdentifier = "TableViewCell"


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: MyCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as MyCell
        let row = indexPath.row
        cell.dayLabel.text = tableDS[row]
        return cell
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        let row = indexPath.row
        println(tableDS[row])

    }

}
```

Comment: Outside of what?  Inside of what?  Is the posted code the working example?

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!  {
                var cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell
                cell.textLabel.text = tableDS[indexPath.row]
                return cell
}
```

This should work.
If you want to use the MVC pattern, create a new singleton class, create the array there, then create a method returning the array.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to initialize your table view with an empty array. When you load your MyViewController from another view controller in the code example below you can pass your data, and change your `let tableDS = [“fdf”, “dfd”]` to `var tableDS = [“fdf”, "dfd"]`. let is used for a constant variables.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "YourMyViewControllerSequeId" {
        let myViewController = segue.destinationViewController as MyViewController
        var myArrayToPass = ["learn swift", "or get a life"];
        myViewController.tableDS = myArrayToPass
        myViewController.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the MVC design pattern for a table view the table view is the view object. The controller is the view controller.

The model is whatever you use to store your data.

The controller object serves as an intermediary between the model and the view.

For a simple table view the model object can be a as simple as an array. The array **is** the model. Thus there is no reason to store the data in a separate object.

If you really want to make your model a completely different object, create a new class. Call it MyTableViewModel. Make your MyTableViewModel class contain an array of your data. Also make MyTableViewModel conform to the UITableViewDatasource protocol. To do that, you'll have to implement several methods - in particular, cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Now in your view controller, create a MyTableViewModel object as a strong property of your view controller, install the array in it, and make it the data source of the table view.

Done.

Again, though, it's quite common to just treat a simple array as your model, and let the view controller serve up cells by implementing cellForRowAtIndexPath in the view controller.